# Firebase Function Not logs any data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I write a function to send a notification to specific users so when I want to test it and log data I can't see it on Logs So what's the problem?

I just trigger databases when I create new order it should log order data but sadly not got anything

[image: DB St]

just i can see this log! I don't know it's for just deploy or something else

[image: Log]

**Code**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://app-9d540.firebaseio.com',
});
// Send notification for user when his order accepted "status : pendding"
exports.acceptOrder = functions.database
  .ref('/Providers/ProvidersOrders/InProgress/{providerUid}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log('snapshot', snapshot.val());
    const {providerUid} = context.params;
    console.log('providerUid', providerUid);
    return null;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you show gets triggered when you create a *provider*, not when you create an order. In other words: the first time you create an order for a provider, the provider node also gets created and your function gets triggered. But if you subsequently add another order to the same provider, your function won't get triggered, since the provider already exists.

If you want to trigger this function on the creation of an *order*, use this:

```
exports.acceptOrder = functions.database
  .ref('/Providers/ProvidersOrders/InProgress/{providerUid}/{orderId}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But it does not work I don't know why!

Comment: OH, it's work now "just restart my app" :D but I have one question can u explain to me what is the log i got in the above screenshot?

Comment: @OliverD Those kind of log comes when you deploy your functions.